How to refactor out code in Blazor OnParameterSet
I have a set of pages that all follow a similar pattern of /{report}/{id} but where {report} is replaced with a concrete name for each page. We also have a singleton reportManager that used to be updated in the page's OnParameterSet
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
   if (reportManager.SelectedId != id) {
       reportManager.SelectedId = id;
   }

   var item = reportManager.SelectedItem;
}

Now this logic has been moved into a component that each of the pages uses. But the as the pages will make calls to reportManager.SelectedItem the component's OnParametersSetAsync needs to be called before the page's OnParametersSetAsync.
Is there any way to reorder this stuff or a better way to extract this logic to some common place.
I've thought about inheritance but in blazor components it is kinda ugly and a bit fiddly if you want the component your are inheriting to enclose the derived component.
I've also thought about creating some page that matches /{report}/{id} and then provides the correct component based on the {report} parameter, but then each time a page is added you then have to update this 'routing' page.
Otherwise I might have to rework the reportManager as it is a bit clunky

I don't think you can reorder page lifecycle events.

As @topsail said Blazor's component lifecycle events follows fixed order, and we can't reorder them directly, but you could work with the lifecycle event to achieve your requirement. Here is the code you could try:
ReportState.cs:
namespace ReportManagementApp.Data
{
    public class ReportState
    {
        public string SelectedId { get; private set; }
        public string SelectedItem { get; private set; }

        public event Action OnChange;

        public void SetSelectedId(string id)
        {
            if (SelectedId != id)
            {
                SelectedId = id;
                // Fetch and set the selected item based on the ID
                SelectedItem = FetchSelectedItem(id);
                NotifyStateChanged();
            }
        }

        private string FetchSelectedItem(string id)
        {
            // Simulate fetching an item based on the ID
            return $"Item for ID: {id}";
        }

        private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();

    }
}

ReportStateProvider.razor:
@using ReportManagementApp.Data
<h3>ReportStateProvider</h3>

@code {
    [Inject] private ReportState ReportState { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter] public string ReportId { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        // Initialize the report state with the provided ReportId
        ReportState.SetSelectedId(ReportId);
    }
  }

ReportPage.razor:
@page "/report/{id}"
@using ReportManagementApp.Data
@inject ReportState ReportState

<h3>Report Page</h3>

<div>
    <p>Selected ID: @ReportState.SelectedId</p>
    <p>Selected Item: @ReportState.SelectedItem</p>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Id { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        // This ensures that ReportState has been set before you use it
        if (ReportState.SelectedId != Id)
        {
            ReportState.SetSelectedId(Id);
        }
    }
   }

NavMenu.razor:
 <div class="nav-item px-3">
     <NavLink href="/report/1" class="nav-link" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix">
         Report 1
     </NavLink>

 </div>



This is essentially what we have at the moment as each of the pages' OnParameterSet method needs the SelectedId check, Which I wanted to pull out into a component such that that check is performed before the page's OnParameterSet,

I suppose this answers the question as presented here, looks like I will have to have another thing
